# Using querySelectorAll on a React component's children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I am trying to render a list of elements lazily by initially rendering only what's in view and then replacing placeholder elements with the real thing as you scroll down using an IntersectionObserver. This keeps the list's length from changing as I add new elements and is much cheaper to render as I'm only listing empty divs when the page loads. Like a poor man's virtualization.

The issue:

The parent element adds its children to the IO as so:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!observer.current) return

    const els = [...document.querySelectorAll(`.list > :nth-child(n + 10})`)]
    els.forEach(el => observer.current.observe(el))
  }, [list])
```

`els` does not always find elements as React renders its elements as it sees fit. The problem is that I don't know how I could do this using ref. Using context I may be able to do this but I'd imagine there would be constant rerendering of the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example can help you understand how to use Refs in your case. I recommend you to read [React Docs about Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Please let me know if you have any doubt.

```js
const MyItem = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (<div ref={ref}>{'ITEM ' + props.index}</div>);
});

const MyList = () => {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
  
  const refsMap = React.useRef(new Map());
  
  const onClickHandler = React.useCallback(() => {
    setList((previousList) => {
      const key = previousList.length;

      return ([
        ...previousList,
        <MyItem key={key} index={key} ref={(ref) => {
          if (ref) {
            refsMap.current.set(key, ref);
          } else {
            refsMap.current.delete(key);
          }
          
          console.log(refsMap.current.get(key));
        }} />
      ]);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type={'button'} onClick={onClickHandler}>{'ADD'}</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        {list}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <MyList />
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Is it really advisable to save components to state like that?